# Remover data e link da impressão

Tags: javascript, css3

Estou fazendo uma tela com diversas informações e imagens, ate ai tudo bem. Meu problema é que ao tentar imprimir essa tela, aparece data no cabeçalho e o link no rodapé. Existe algum jeito de remover isso sem ser pela configuração do browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não, não existe.

Essa *"feature"* é totalmente independente do seu código fonte. Não existe *markup* que os faça desaparecer, já que isso não vem de nenhuma especificação do HTML, e não há código Javascript para controlar isso pois os desenvolvedores dos navegadores em geral não publicam API's para isso. Ainda que existisse uma API única e *cross-browser* para controlar a impressão dessa forma, remover essas informações da impressão seria interferir com algo que é escolha do usuário, e portanto poderia ser visto como uma falha de segurança.

Aqui e ali você pode ver alguém sugerir [uma forma de contornar isso, ao tentar controlar as margens de impressão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page). Isso é uma **gambiarra** e não é garantido que funcionará em todos os navegadores - e mesmo que funcione, não se sabe por quanto tempo continuará a funcionar. Eu pessoalmente acredito que existe um lugar especial no inferno para todos aqueles que tentam burlar o comportamento padrão dos navegadores.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela ajuda.